# Java executes only first command from .sh file

Tags: java, ubuntu

The problem is that I am running a .sh file from which has 3 commands using Java's Runtime.exec("") method but only first command from .sh file gets executed.

Can anyone answer what could be the problem ?

Here is my code.

```
    Process process  =      Runtime.getRuntime().exec("run.sh");
    process.waitFor();
    DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(process.getInputStream());
                    System.out.println(d.readLine());
                    System.out.println("test");
```

run.sh script is as follows :

```
     #! /bin/sh
     echo "start"
     ls -a
     echo "stop"
```

It executes the run.sh but only first command is getting executed(echo command). I tried with different commands but result remains the same. Only first one gets executed.

Comment: You should probably include the source of your java class and the shell script.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is usually best to provide some sample code - in your case, can you show how you are calling the script and how the script looks like, and describe what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

> DataInputStream d = new DataInputStream(process.getInputStream());
>   System.out.println(d.readLine());

The shell script is executing all the commands, but you are just reading the first line from the process' input stream that contains all the output of the shell script. Instead, read till the end of stream and you would see the output of all the commands.

```
String output = StringUtils.join(IOUtils.readLines(process.getInputStream));
```

Both [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html) and [IOUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html) are utility classes from apache commons lang and commons IO respectively.

If you don't want to use the commons libraries, then

```
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder;
String line;
while ((line = d.readLine()) != null) {
    output.append(line);
}
System.out.println(output.toString());
```